# Parameter list from launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rosserial to pull a list of gains from the parameter server, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the `<param>` tag to create a list of values in a launch file.

EDIT: Specifically, trying to make one parameter of 'list' type, and then could be pulled in one go as shown [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Overview/Parameters).

EDIT2: `<rosparam param = "~pid">[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 100]</rosparam>` works to load a list, however roslaunch seems to automatically parse the values as strings

EDIT3: `<rosparam param = "pid">[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 100.0]</rosparam>` works fine

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55987/parameter-list-from-launch-file/) by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4518 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use the tag to load the list you can use a yaml file like so:

```
- item
- item2
```

However, if you want to set the param directly as a list within the launch file using 
[here](http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/pr2_symbolic_planning/tidyup_actions/launch/continual-planning-tidyup.launch) is an example. Look for the `planner_options` parameter.

```
<rosparam param="planner_options">
        - (planning_scene_navstack_init@libplanner_modules_pr2.so /map 0.05 1)
        - (putdown_init@libputdown_modules.so /map)
</rosparam>
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4